# how to rectify the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error in getting json response using jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to get a jQuery mobile app read data from a server as json format. When 
I load the page, I get the error like'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' 
in my chrome console. 
I'm new for json and jquery,so give me any suggestions for rectify this error.
thanks in advance.

Here's my Javscript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#leads-list').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://fg.com/rest/view.php?sessid=35e85b084ff41894170a0',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            success: successData,
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });

        function successData(data) {
            var response = data.message;
            alert('data=' + response);
        }
    });
});
```

and my php code is:

```
    $jsonResponse = Zend_JSON::decode($response['body']);
$rtnobj->message=$jsonResponse;
echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($rtnobj) . ')';
```

The JSON response:

```
({
    "message": {
        "success":true,
        "result":[
            {
                "lead_no":"LEA11",
                "lastname":"Venu",
                "firs‌​tname":"Yatagiri",
                "company":"RSalesArm IT Services Ltd",
                "email":"venu_yatagiri@rsalesarm.com",
                "id":"10x125"
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Comment: May we see the output of json_encode($rtnobj);

Comment: ({"message":{"success":true,"result":[{"lead_no":"LEA11","lastname":"Venu","firstname":"Yatagiri","company":"RSalesArm IT Services Ltd","email":"venu_yatagiri@rsalesarm.com","id":"10x125"}]}})

Comment: @cheliyan You can edit your own question to insert answers to any comments; any later visitors to this site then will see the full question with all its details. Why are you adding the round braces in `'('. json_encode($rtnobj) . ')'` – I think that could be the error…

Answer (score 1):

When I copy the json above into my editor, I see instead of

```
"firstname":"Yatagiri",
```

the following:

```
"firs?tname":"Yatagiri",
```

...there is a character between the **s** and the **t** in **firstname**.

The viewsource here shows me:

```
firs&zwnj;&#8203;tname
```

You should remove these characters when they are coming from your PHP-script.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in the line

```
echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($rtnobj) . ')';
```

It should read

```
echo json_encode( $rtnobj );
```

To create a function call from your JSON response you would use JavaScript, not PHP.